# When I call this method, it returns 0

Tags: macos, cocoa

Logic is: read data from a view (3 textfields) then when a button is pressed, sum data which stored in the model and print it out.

<--Header file-->

```
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class QuoteAttributes;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *amountOfHardware;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *amountOfPrinter;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *amountOfSoftware;
@property (strong) QuoteAttributes *quickQuote;


- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender;
- (void) setValueTotheForm;

@end
```

See the following Code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "QuoteAttributes.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize amountOfHardware;
@synthesize amountOfPrinter;
@synthesize amountOfSoftware;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (void) setValueTotheForm{
    [self.quickQuote setNumHardware:[self.amountOfSoftware intValue]];
    [self.quickQuote setNumPrinter:[self.amountOfPrinter intValue]];
    [self.quickQuote setNumSoftware:[self.amountOfSoftware intValue]];

    int totalQuote = [self.quickQuote numHardware] + [self.quickQuote numPrinter] + [self.quickQuote numSoftware];

    NSLog(@"%d", totalQuote);
}

- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
    [self setValueTotheForm];
}
@end
```

However, when I call this method, it prints `0`

Comment: What are the values of `self.amountOfSoftware` and `self.amountOfPrinter` in this function?

Comment: this method has no return type, it's just void

Comment: @AdamRosenfield as I described, they will be read from 3 textfields which are the 3 values assigned to self.amountOfSoftware and self.amountOfPrinter

Comment: @phix23 it returns nothing but just print a value out ... so can be void

Comment: Maybe 0 + 0 + 0 equals 0... Weird indeed, but it happens sometimes...

Comment: @Macmade well, I am sure 3 different values are type into the textfields

Comment: @Twocode Then maybe your outlets are not set-up properly, meaning your iVars are nil... Hence zero...

Comment: @Macmade plz have a look at the header file, don't think they are wrong(could be, but I cannot see), and when debugging, their values were assigned properly.

Comment: @Macmade ok, I know why now, I didn't initiate the object at the beginning, so there way no way to store value into the memory, thanks for the comment and you are much better than the ones only know how to click downgrade button :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should initiate the object first :

```
    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    QuoteAttributes *qa = [[QuoteAttributes alloc] init];
    [self setQuickQuote: qa];
}
```

then the abovementioned code will work.